# Using GPay in WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

may be someone have an experience in this question.
A have read official Google documentation about Binding JavaScript code to Android code.
But I know exactly, we can use GPay in WebView without Binding JavaScript code, without additional web clients. Only WebViewClient and WebChromeClient should be initialized correctly.

Maybe someone did it ?

I try to use simple WebView implementation:

```
        val destination = "https://google.com"
        val myWeb: WebView = findViewById(R.id.myWeb)
        myWeb.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWeb.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        myWeb.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true

        myWeb.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient(){

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                Log.d("abcde", "The url onPageFinished is $url")
            }
        }

        myWeb.loadUrl(destination)
```

[my result when i press the GPay button in my WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA1bR.jpg)

I have no see the errors in urls of WebView. I think the problem with opening new windovs in web view.
I have reversed a little bit, the application, which can do it. Seems, it usese overrided methods onCreateWindow and onCloseWindow window in the WebChromeClient.
And heve import, which I have no in my code:

import android.webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport;